# Automatically recycle app pool before .net debug

Tags: asp.net, iis

Before the start of debugging for my MVC application, I want to recycle the IIS app pool it is using.  I can't find any type of script I could create or setting I could change from online searches.

Does anyone know a way to recycle the assigned app pool when I start the debug process in .NET?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restart the whole IIS,just issue `iisreset` command.Or You can write a simple Powershell script to do this

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$mysite = "Default Web Site"
$pool = (Get-Item "IIS:\Sites\$mysite"| Select-Object applicationPool).applicationPool
Restart-WebAppPool $pool
```